# How to disable the function of ESC key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my chat application there are some text fields which gets the user login details.

When filling the user details, if a user suddenly pressed the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, the data will be lost.

If need to disable the function of <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, which event I need to use? How can I do that.

My JavaScript code is:

```
function esc(e){
    e = e || window.event || {};
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(charCode == 27){
    return false;
    }
}
```

I searched a lot in Stack Overflow and Google; nothing worked. Please, can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: the escape key does nothing special per default. What do you meen by the data will be lost? You could use a keydown eventlistener to react accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Data lost means that,the entered text in the text fields are lost.

Comment: I need that ESC will not work in my application . How to do this ?

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle or give us a link to show what you mean?

Comment: @Christoph nothing happened .any more ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to control the " F5 , Esc , BackSpace(BS) " keys with the following code.

My Java Script code will be ,

```
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", win_onkeydown_handler);

function win_onkeydown_handler() {
    switch (event.keyCode) {

    case 116 : // 'F5'
         event.returnValue = false;
         event.keyCode = 0;
         break;  

    case 27: // 'Esc'
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        break;

    case 08: // 'BackSpace'
        if (event.srcElement.tagName == "INPUT"
                || event.srcElement.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

Thanks who are all supported me to do this and for your suggestions.

Comment: you should **NOT** use this code! This only works in Internet Explorer and will fail in all other browsers. The correct way to bind a eventhandler is via `addEventListener` and never via `attachEvent`!

Answer (score 7):

You can bind an eventlistener to your input field to catch the Event when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed and supress it.

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 27){
         alert("Escape is not allowed!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcdZm/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... nothing happened .any more ideas ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by nothing happens? This code [works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/JEhjG/). Did you include this script AFTER your input element? Take a look at the webdeveloper console (press F12) an look for errors.

Comment: Thank for your reply...Works in Fiddle but not working in my browser.

Comment: @Anand assuming your answer, you are using Internet Explorer. Be aware however, that your code will break in all other browsers!

Comment: See the solution which I gave.It works in all browsers.I will debug why your code is not working for me.Any way thanks for your support  Mr.Christoph.

Comment: Also see my new question in [My new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o).Help me if possible.

Comment: This does not work in full screen mode, it doesn't prevent user to exit full screen...

Comment: Thanks, it led me to right direction. However, all three are deprecated. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)
`Warning: Do not use this property, as it is deprecated. Instead, get the Unicode value of the character using the key property.`

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for a login popup code:

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
    // alert('not allowed !!!');
        // or any other code
     return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess 'keydown' does not work in Chrome. Better to use 'keyup' instead

Comment: Thanks for your support.I dont have knowlede in JQuery.can u please convert it in to JS.

Comment: Buddy, this is probably the simplest 2-line code you may get. Why not start with jQyery today !! :)

Comment: @Riju You are guessing wrong! How do you come to this assumption?

Comment: @Christoph .. No offence... Its just my humble opinion.

Comment: @Riju It's not about opinions, it's about facts, and these are either true or false. And I would consider your statement. http://jsfiddle.net/JEhjG/

Comment: @Christoph .. I never questioned your code. all I said that the code that I gave was simpler and smaller. And what harm will the guy get if he learns jQuery ? After all, libraries like these have been developed out of a necessity when plain javascript fails to provide simple solutions, OR a solution at all, for that matter. Again no offense buddy.. :)

Comment: @Riju I feel offended in no way. I am just refering to your: "I guess 'keydown' does not work in Chrome." which is plain wrong. I was not questioning your recommendation of jQuery;)

Comment: @Christoph.. It was  a guess ('I guess'.. ) so its allowed to be wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using jquery to limit entry to numbers

```
    $(inputBox).keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        var allowed_keys = [
            46, // delete
            8, // backspace
                 ];
        if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, allowed_keys) != -1) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
    });
```